# What Schema.org should be used for user profiles?

Tags: schema.org, users

I might be taking this a little too far outside of the box, but I'm curious about what Schema.org type to use for a user-profile on my site.

On the front page for instance (`http://www.findgamers.us`), a random gamer profile loads every time the page is loaded.

Would I use the `Person` type to make that structured data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could use the [`Person` type](http://schema.org/Person).

For a dedicated user profile page (i.e., one user per page), you could use the [`ProfilePage` type](http://schema.org/ProfilePage):

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProfilePage">

  <div itemprop="about mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  </div>

</body>
```